# how to secure 2 paths at same time with spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this issue.

There is a configuration in spring security

```
<intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="ROLE_PROFILE" />
```

Works as expected...

Then, for some reasons (I cannot change) , there is another url

```
/myurl/profile
```

both `/profile` and `/myurl/profile` are answered by the same controller and do exactly the same, only the url changes, and the profile of access is the same.

I tried to do this

```
 <intercept-url pattern="*/profile" access="ROLE_PROFILE" />
```

But doesnt work, also tried with **. Is there any way I do this configuration without have to add a new line? (are about 50 rules to add), Can I specify more than one pattern to intercept?

Comment: thanks @chrylis, that is another option but I want to know if there is any wildcard to use and avoid repeat the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use this /**/profile, it should intercept both /myurl/profile and
>   /profile.

Your code will look something like below:-

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/**/profile" access="ROLE_PROFILE" />
```